# Benefits of overloading += or -= operators

Tags: c++, oop, templates, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

Recently I have done an assignment, on overloading basic functionalists(+,-,conjugate...) of complex class using templates. I had to sweat out a little to find out the proper return type, (casting to higher type), but at the end, I got it working perfectly. 
This is how my class looks like -

```
template <typename T> class complex_t
{ 
private:
    T real;
    T imaginary;

public:

complex_t(T X, T Y)
  {
    real=X;
    imaginary=Y;
  }
}
```

But I didnt get full marks, because I didn't implement the +=, -= etc. operators. **Why is it important to implement those operators?** Whether doing that really provide any particular benefits?
Can anyone share some thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: that depends. its not entirely necessary to implement those operators. it depends on the kind of class and what its supposed to do

Comment: It depends on the class. As it stands, without any code, your question is to vague to give any kind of reasonable answer to.

Comment: In your case, it appears to be important in order to get full marks. C++ truly caters to a huge variety of different use cases!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+=` and friends work in-place, so you don't have to return a new instance of your class. For complex numbers, that might not be much of a problem, but with larger structures the copying might be expensive.

As an example, suppose that you're implementing vectors, in the mathematical sense, supporting arbitrary lengths.

```
class Vector
{
    std::vector<double> elements;

  public:
    Vector operator+(double x)
    {
        // must return a copy!
        Vector v(*this);
        for (size_t i=0; i < elements.size(); i++)
            v.elements[i] += x;
        return v;
    }

    Vector &operator+=(double x)
    {
        // in-place operation
        for (size_t i=0; i < elements.size(); i++)
            elements[i] += x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Out of interest: Is this still an issue with move semantics in c++11?  If you define a move constructor, is the compiler smart enough to use it for the assingment in a `f2 = f2 - f1` statement?  (I realise this is irrelevant to the question - just wondering)

Comment: Actually, duh.  Looking at your edit with the code sample makes it clear to me that move semantics are not going to be any use.

Comment: @Martin: Move semantics will partially alleviate the problem (not the move constructor, but the move assignment operator).  It still unnecessarily creates a third object, but copying it back into f2 is much more efficient.

Comment: Vector v(*this); Is this a reference to the first operand? When making any changes to the variable, v, that will be reflected in other references , ie, (*this) in this case?

Comment: @jb_2519: no, it constructs a new `Vector` by copying `*this`.

Comment: You missed a return statement on `operator+`.

Comment: @danielkza: actually, I missed the return statements on both methods :) Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Overloading operator - allows users of your class "Foo" to write code like:

```
Foo f1 = ...;
Foo f2 = ...;
f2 = f2 - f1;
```

Overloading operator -= allows users to write

```
Foo f1 = ...;
Foo f2 = ...;

f2 -= f1;
```

Unless you overload -=, the second example just won't work, which your users will probably expect to work.

**Edit to incorporate efficiency point**  (My answer is getting upvoted, so I thought I'd summarise a recurring point from other answers to keep all the details the one spot.  Credit to larsmans and Benjamin)

`f2 -= f1` is often more efficient than `f2 = f2 - f1` for two reasons:

- `operator -` needs to take a copy of `this`, before modifying the copy and returning it.
- `operator -` also needs to return the result by value (it can't return a reference to a stack object), possibly causing a second copy.

`operator -=` on the other hand, modifies `this` in place, so makes no copies.

Answer (score 9):

If you have two objects, A and B, and you want to increment A by B, without `operator+=`, you would do this:

```
A = A + B;
```

This will, in normal implementations, involve the creation of a third (temporary) object, which is then copied back to A.  However, with `operator+=`, A can be modified in place, so this is normally less work, and therefore more efficient.

Perhaps more important, is that it's idiomatic to the language.  C++ programmers expect that if they can do this:

```
A = A + B;
```

They can also do this:

```
A += B;
```

Comment: Also, implementing `operator+=` as a member function makes it simple to write `operator+` as a free function without making it a friend: `MyType operator+(const MyType& lhs, const MyType& rhs) { return MyType(lhs) += rhs; }`.

Answer (score 5):

First, if you give me a class with a + operator, I would expect += to work as well.
However, this does not come automagically, so you need to implement it.

Second, as others pointed out before, depending on the implementation of your class and the definition of your sum operation, you might be able to implement += more efficienlty than merely re-using you're + operator in the obvious way (which is the way it could be auto-generated by the compiler, but isn't).

Answer (score 4):

Because that's the way the built-in operators work.  Any time you have
a binary operator `op`, you have a variant
`op=` such that `a op= b;` is the
equivalent of `a = a op b;`, except that `a` is only
evaluated once.  If you're defining overloaded operators, you should
pattern their behavior on the built-in operators (and if the behavior
can't be naturally patterned on the built-in operators, you shouldn't be
overloading).  Providing `+`, but not providing `+=`, is about like
providing `<`, but not providing `<=`.

In practice, the usual way of implementing arithmetic operators is to
define only the `op=` operators in the class, and then
to derive from an instantiation of a class template which defines the
`op` operators using the `op=`
operators, something like:

```
class MyType : public BinaryOperators<MyType>
{
public:
    MyType& operator+=( MyType const& other );
    //  ...
};
```

where `BinaryOperators` looks something like:

```
template <typename ValueType>
class BinaryOperators
{
    friend ValueType
    operator+( ValueType const& lhs, ValueType const& rhs )
    {
        ValueType results( lhs );
        results += rhs;
        return results;
    }
    //  ...
};
```

(In this case, the `friend` declaration is only a trick to allow the
free functions to be fully defined within the class.)

Comment: +1, Another similar trick to the CRTP would be to create templated operators in a namespace, add a *tag* there and inherit from the empty tag. The CRTP is cleaner from the language point of view although it might look a bit more complex for starters. I would, on the other hand, have the binary operators take the first argument by value, allowing the compiler to move in C++11 in some contexts.

Answer (score 3):

The + operator will by design allocate and construct a completely new object, while the += operator can modify the existing object. That allows you to implement the += operator much more efficiently than what would happen when the user substitutes it with `val1 = val1 + val2`.

Also, when I know that a class overloads +, I would also expect it to overload +=.

Comment: Now I understood it, everyone 'expects' += or -= normally :) I will take care of it from next time onward Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Besides the possibility that other programmers would expect the += to be overriden, I suppose it could be necessary for inheritence and overriding functionality. In a very abstract and probably incorrect sense, Imagine we want to perform an operation on a list of Integers that include our special Integer:

```
MyModifiedInteger extends Integer {
  private boolean bigNumberFlag = false;
  ...
  @Override
  public void +=(int i) {
    this = this + i;
    if (this > 100) {
      this.bigNumberFlag = true;
    }
  }
}
MyModifiedInteger myModifiedInt = new MyModifiedInteger();
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
integers.add(myModifiedInt);
for (Integer i : integers) {
  i+=5;
}
```

The idea here (if I applied my java inheritence correctly) is to utilise the += operator on my Integers as well as the inheriting classes that may handle the += operation differently.